# the content of log4j.properties in log4j V2 and formating the logger output (for instance adding time stamp)

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am doing a Java project and I have already integrated the `Log4j API Version 2` into my programme (CLearly for the first time and I have no idea how it works , thus if my question seems easy don't put the blame on me ) . The content of my log4j.properties is as follow :

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,SAWAN
log4j.appender.SAWAN=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.SAWAN.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
```

and then I imported the log4j library into my class and for debugging purpose I've written the following and the output is shown as well

```
    //My Code
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    logger.debug("Sample debug message");
    logger.info("Sample info message");
    logger.warn("Sample warn message");
    logger.error("Sample error message");
    logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");


    //Output 
    DEBUG - Sample debug message
    INFO - Sample info message
    WARN - Sample warn message
    ERROR - Sample error message
    FATAL - Sample fatal message
```

which means that the log4j is working fine . How ever I'd like to change the format of the output and add time stamp to it . Based on my research on the other questions asked in this site and referring to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html I know that I need to use something like :

```
[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

but once I added this to my log4j.properties I recived an error .My question is where should I specify the output format for my log outputs .

Here are the libraries I've imported as well :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
```

Worth mentioning that I've tried adding the following to my log4j.properties : `log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d %c - %m%n`

yet I am keep getting errors that some thing is wrong with my log4j.properties  which is not the case when I remove it and it would work fine :)

Comment: The link you provided to `PatternLayout` comes from log4j1 not log4j2. Be careful you're reading the correct documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need a file named `log4j2.properties` on your classpath to be picked up automatically.

Documentation from Log4j2:

> Log4j has the ability to automatically configure itself during
>   initialization. When Log4j starts it will locate all the
>   ConfigurationFactory plugins and arrange them in weighted order from
>   highest to lowest. As delivered, Log4j contains four
>   ConfigurationFactory implementations: one for JSON, one for YAML, one
>   for properties, and one for XML.
>
> Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and,
>   if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>   ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
>
> 1. If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will
>      look for log4j2-test.properties in the classpath.
> 2. If no such file is found the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or log4j2-test.yml in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn in the classpath.
> 4. If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.
> 5. If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath.
> 6. If a properties file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the classpath.
> 7. If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or log4j2.jsn on the classpath.
> 8. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.
> 9. If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

You can find all documentation on log4j2 configuration here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Thanks to [D.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284624/d-b) for pointing out the correct answer.

Comment: log4j2 does allow configuration with properties according to the [configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) page. See the section titled **Configuration with Properties**, however the file name and syntax is different.